# Hidden app in Apple App Store

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I have an app that (depending on the user) needs to download a companion app.  I'd like to have this companion app in the app store so that the user can easily download it but I don't want the companion app public to everyone, I just want to be able to access it through a download command in my primary app.

Is such a thing feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The only thing you could do is not providing any search tags, which would make it very hard for users to find it, or create an enterprise in-house-distribution system (which probably is not what you want).

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763210/can-i-hide-or-make-my-iphone-application-unsearchable-on-the-app-store
- https://developer.apple.com/enterprise/